# How TestNG before\after methods should work with groups

Tags: java, maven, testng

I have java project with my tests and Maven to build it.

Test structure:

- QuickTest (child of TestBase)
- LongTest (child of TestBase)
- TestBase (parent of QuickTest and LongTest)

TestBase contain only three methods:

- `@BeforeClass`  - to run browser
- `@BeforeMethod` - to open main page
- `@AfterSuite` - to close browser

QuickTest contain 4 quick test-methods with `@Test` annotations and `(groups = {"quick"})`
LongTest contain a `@DataProvider` and one `@Test` to use it, with `(groups = {"long"})`

In Maven I have some profiles to start different browsers. My goal is to use:

`mvn test -P ie9 -Dgroups=quick`

to run only quick tests, but I'm having a problem with my `TestBase` class. I always add `@BeforeClass` and `@BeforeMethod` as well as `(alwaysRun = true)` which is working fine.

But my `@AfterSuite` method doesn't work. When I add `(alwaysRun = true)` to it then this method will always log an error and fail.

For quick group i want test order:

BeforeClass -> BeforeMethod -> TestMethod1 -> BeforeMethod -> TestMethodX -> AfterSuite

For long group i want order:

BeforeClass -> BeforeMethod -> TestMethodWithData1 -> BeforeMethod -> TestMethodWithDataX -> AfterSuite

What annotations should I use and what should my testng.xml look like?

Comment: If your annotation is `@BeforeClass` to open the browser, why don't you use `@AfterClass` to close the browser?  That seems to make a lot more sense.

Comment: @MrTi thank for advise. I change '@AfterSuite' to '@AfterClass'. Now if i run only single test class it's work great. But if i want to run more than one class at once, then work only first class, the second will skip. New test order is: BeforeClass -> BeforeMethod -> TestX -> AfterClass -> BeforeMethod. BeforeClass won't start before each test-class, only at first and all other test-methods are skip.

Comment: I'm confused about what your are saying.  `@BeforeClass` will run before all methods in the class, and `@AfterClass` will run after all methods in the class.  If you are running another class, then it will need a `@Before`/`@After` as well

Comment: @MrTi yea, i know that. but all of my before\after methods are the same for all of my tests. And i store them in a parent class TestBase other tests are just a class that extends TestBase.

Comment: I would like to recommend jbehave for you. I suppose your tests doing somethig in the page that is why you made a super class for them. You can use BeforeStory/AfterStory annotation for open/close the browser. You should write story files and steps and steps have order so you can log in and after that log out and so on.